# pfSense allowing inbound sip phones, but not sip trunk

Tags: voip, sip, pfsense

I am currently trying to get an inbound trunk working on a remote Asterisk machine.  The ip phones are remote and connecting just fine through port 5060 (I can make internal calls to voicemail, other phones) and I can make outbound calls fine.  I cannot, however, receive calls.  `sissak -vv -s -sip:------@asterisk.aikester.com` returns a timeout.  There is nothing in the asterisk logs.

Any help would be appreciated, I've been struggling to get it working all day.